# Jet SQL/MS Access - Query, count of tasks, sum of time, by user

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, jet-sql

I would really appreciate help in achieving the correct output, I want to understand how it works and self teach.

I have one table:

[image: tasks table]

I would like to achieve the below results from one query:

```
user_name  |   task   |   CountOftask  |   SumOftime
    U1           1            1              00:15
    U2           1            1              00:25
    U2           2            1              00:05
    U3           2            1              00:20
    U3           3            2              00:40
```

#### re: the table 'tasks':

The time field is date/time hh:nn.
The date field is irrelevant for the query at this stage - I want all historic data returned.

#### re: the query:

I would like to see a Count of task, SUM of time and Group by user_name & task, using one query with a sub select, instead of two separate queries.

Thanks for your time

#### Edit:

I can create this output, but I use two queries (Q1) to convert the time to integer, summing it. (Q2) using Q1 convert the integer back to time hh:mm.

#### Q1:

```
SELECT 
user_name
, task
, Count(task) AS CountOftask
, Sum(CLng(24*60*CDate([time]))) AS time_mins
FROM tasks
GROUP BY user_name, task;
```

#### Q2:

```
SELECT 
[301 SF count of task].user_name
, [301 SF count of task].task
, [301 SF count of task].CountOftask
, [time_mins]\60 & Format([time_mins] Mod 60,"\:00") AS Time_sum
FROM [301 SF count of task]
;
```

I would like to be able to do this in one query, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show what you've attempted so people can help you with that. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service

Comment: Certainly, I didn't want the post to be too long. I will amend the original post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Select
    user_name,
    Max(task) As max_task,
    Count(*) As task_count,
    CDate(Sum([time])) As total_time
From
    YourTable
Group By    
    user_name,
    task
```

**Edit** - if *time* is text:

```
    Sum(CDate([time])) As total_time
```

or forced to date value:

```
    CDate(Sum(CDate([time]))) As total_time
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Access doesn't like the CDate function on my field. Error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: You didn't tell, that _time_ is text.

Comment: The time is stored as date/time data type with a format of hh:nn. I've just tried the forced date value you suggested above - **CDate(Sum(CDate([time]))) As total_time**. It works perfectly, thank you for your time here. Can I ask, why would the original **CDate(Sum[time])) AS total_time** as you suggested not work as the time field is NOT text? Thanks

Comment: Well, if your _time_ was Date, the values would be right aligned. On your picture, however, they are left aligned, so I'm not convinced that _time_ is Date.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I created a dummy table (to hide my data) so I've been looking at the wrong table! Lesson learned. Thanks again

Comment: OK. That explains.